# Lobbyist's Counterpart

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

A [*lobbyist*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lobbyist) is a person tries to influence the votes of legislators on behalf of a special interest. What would the correct term be for the legislators being lobbied? *Lobbyee* might be a logical conclusion, but it looks and sounds terrible (at least to me).

Note: If the word you suggest has more subtle connotations, e.g. it describes a legislator that is particularly easily swayed lobbyists, please be sure to mention that.

Comment: "Hono[u]rable member".

Comment: By your definition, *legislators*. Also, [the distinguished gentleman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Distinguished_Gentleman) (or lady).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Well for example, I think it would be fair to describe one legislator who tries to influence his or her co-legislators as a *lobbyist*. In this situation, what term would you use to describe the *other* legislators?

Comment: @p.s.w.g No. That makes them an *advocate*. A lobbyist is someone specifically employed to lobby (or advocate) on behalf of some third-party.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch You might be right. Maybe I'm using the terms incorrectly. There could also be a difference in British English vs. American English. I just finished donating blood, so it's also possible I'm not thinking 100% clearly at the moment :P

Comment: @p.s.w.g Perhaps that's just common usage. It's a comment, maybe someone will have a good answer. Also, eat the snack they gave you.

Comment: They give snacks away?  You now have my attention, pesky blood thieves.

Comment: Today's lobbied is tomorrow's lobbyist. Today's lobbyist is tomorrows lobbied. Revolving door.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be answered in many ways that all depend upon who is being lobbied and what their position and organization to which they belong is. (e.g. Senator, Chairman, Legislator, etc.)

Some suggestions that are irrespective of who or what is being lobbied:

> [**target**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/target) : a place, thing, or person at which an attack is aimed

<sub>Merriam-Webster</sub>

Has the connotation of the lobbying being an attack or some kind, that the end goal of the lobbying is somehow harmful to the person using this term to describe the action. Synonyms with varying degrees of this connotation include: *prey, quarry, game*

> [**mark**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mark) : **15.b.** *slang* the intended victim of a swindler, hustler, or the like: The cardsharps picked their marks from among the tourists on the cruise ship.

<sub>dictionary.com</sub>

Connotes a degree of deceit on the part of the lobbyist. Combined with ***easy* mark**, connotes one who is easily taken advantage of. Synonyms include: *dupe, (clay) pigeon, sucker, doormat.*

More neutrally, we have the logical **lobbyee** (or **lobbee**) and **lobbied** as others have suggested, but you could consider:

> [**colleague**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/colleague) : an associate in a profession or in a civil or ecclesiastical office

<sub>Merriam-Webster</sub>

Has no connotation of what the association with the lobbyist is. Combined with a adjective phrase, such as *colleagues in the House and Senate*, it could fit into your usage. However, it could cast the impression that lobbyists and private organizations are an essential part of the system. Synonyms include: *counterpart, peer, confederate*. Near synonyms with a definite negative connotation include: *crony, chum, co-conspirator, accomplice*.

Neutral, near synonyms to **lobby** include *influence, solicit, approach, accost*, which have more reasonable forms of past-tense-direct-object: the *influencee/d, solicited, approached,* or *accostee*.

You could also use a general term which makes their role obvious when partnered with lobbyist, such as the power holder, incumbent, or office holder.

Comment: Thank you, this has given me a lot of options to play with. I think I like *target* the most as a general term because it's used pretty commonly in various political contexts (at least in the US), but the other ones you've suggested will work well other situations.

Answer (score 1):

The lobbyist "lobbies." The legislator is "lobbied."